# Swift Programming issues: Exceptions causing my app to crash AND auto-layout localization issues

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, exception, error-handling

I am writing my first app using Swift.  It's a simple music player that's designed to randomly play songs from different genres on my iPhone. I built the UI and the code according the specifications of a YouTube tutorial I watched (https://youtu.be/aiXvvL1wNUc), but my app crashes when I try to run it, either in simulator or on my phone.  I keep getting two messages.

First is a warning on the storyboard about how fixed width constraints may cause auto clipping  (width is set at 120).

[image]

The second issue I'm running into also happens when I try to run the simulator.

I get an exception issue that says

> reason: '-`[UITableViewController loadView]` instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

I'm including a screenshot of this error as well.

[image]

Any help here would be awesome.  If anyone would like a closer look, I also saved the entire code to a Dropbox, so just let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate the View Controller?

Comment: Real quick, where would I find that code???  Scene delegate, app delegate?  Again, I'm a total newcomer to this... :/

Comment: From skimming through the tutorial, make sure you set the class in storyboard. 3:20 in the video. Make sure it's a `UIViewController`.

Comment: I think you should find a better tutorial. First of all that guy himself is an unexperienced developer, so his coding practices are not great. Secondly, this tutorial is 2 years old, now it's much better to learn with something more recent that teaches you latest things, like SwiftUI.

Comment: It sounds like your view controller is subclassing `UITableViewController` but you used a `UIViewController` in your storyboard scene

Comment: I switched the storyboard class back to UIViewController, and now the app works fine, until I push a button, then it crashes again... his video HAS been useful, but, yeah, it's a few years old now.